# Is there a dashboard for Raspberry Pi?

Tags: monitoring, processor-speed

I'd like to remotely be able to check RasPi's status, including:

- processor speed, usage
- free disk space
- the CPU temperature
- top processes
- ...

... as a dashboard-like web page.

I know I could (manually) check each of these from a ssh-connected console, but I'd rather get the big picture from a (maybe) "read-only" web page.

Ability to show time graphs of aforementioned parameters would be extra-nice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This looks promosing too: [Ground Control](http://jondot.github.io/groundcontrol/)

Comment: This one is awesome!

Answer (score 5):

There are many tools out there for exactly what you are asking.  phpSysInfo should do the trick as well as DarkStat, nagios, cacti, mrtg, the list goes on.  It is a matter of personal preference and desired ability that is not to heavy (Many of these are resource hogs, designed for a powerhouse server).  A quick google for `debian web-based monitors` should provide you a much more exhaustive list.

Or you could always write your own :)

Answer (score 4):

This looks promising: 
https://github.com/cgoldberg/linux-stats-dashboard

[image]

I'll update the answer after I get to try it on RasPi.